# Android: Speech to text?

Tags: android, sample

Ive had a look at the following sample code: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

But i cant get it to run on the emulator. Is the layout.xml avaible for this file? Do i need to install another app in order for this one to work? All i want is a simple demo that prints out the words that the app have recognized. Thanks

Comment: Why it doesn't run? You should have some details about the error in the console or in LogCat

Comment: Im getting "recognizer not present", do i need to install some other app in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

These codes do not run in the emulator.. Try running it on an actual device. Since the microphone present in the laptop/desktop is not compatible with the emulator but this is not the case in an actual phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse ApiDemos is part of the sample apps available through the Android SDK and AVD manager.  Open that up and select the sample packages for the Android version you are working with.  That will give you what you need.